# Is there a way to access the documents stored inside a one-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query

Upon fetching results from a mongo database, my documents are stored inside a one-dimensional array in the following form:
Name of array: result,

```
result = [{
     _id: 5e3a5a39743a88182f4dc267,
    ID: 1,
    column_1: 'R1C1',
    column_2: 'R1C2',
    column_3: 'R1C3',
    column_4: 'R1C4',
    column_5: 'R1C5',
    column_6: 'R1C6',
    column_7: 'R1C7',
    column_8: 'R1C8',
    column_9: 'R1C9',
    .....
}, {
     _id: 5e3a5a39743a88182f4dc271,
    ID: 2,
    column_1: 'R1C1',
    column_2: 'R1C2',
    column_3: 'R1C3',
    column_4: 'R1C4',
    column_5: 'R1C5',
    column_6: 'R1C6',
    column_7: 'R1C7',
    column_8: 'R1C8',
    column_9: 'R1C9',
    .....
},
...
]
```

There are 1000 such fields in every documents and 10000 documents respectively.
I used the following command to fetch the results and store into an array:

```
db.collection('Employee').find({}).limit(1).toArray(function (err, result)
```

My motto is to fetch and display only one record from the 'result' array such as,
only `column_1: R1C1` and like that. I am not able to access it individually, please help me out with this issue and if possible provide with the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe simply `db.collection.find({}, {column_1:1} )`?

Comment: I am confused. In your query, you only keep one document (limit (1)). Why? In your ```result``` you write ```.....``` but we don't know what is the __last__ element so your cardinalities are not illustrated. e.g for object ```{_id: 5e3a5a39743a88182f4dc267}``` what is its last column: ```column_1000```? Your expected output is also not clear: In your result (again) there are multiple occurrences of ```column_1: R1C1```: one in object ```_id: 5e3a5a39743a88182f4dc267```  and one in object ```_id: 5e3a5a39743a88182f4dc271``` which one to choose?

Comment: limit(1) I forgot to remove before pasting the code, thanks for correcting. And yes, every document contains the same key: field, which starts from column_1: R1C1 - column_n: RnCn where (0 < n < 1001)

Comment: I want to choose just any document with any 'ID' or object_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second argument to `find` called projection to select specific fields to be returned. See [documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

For example

```
db.collection('Employee')
   .find({}, {column_1: 1})
   .limit(1)
   .toArray(function (err, result)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but instead I had to use .project({}) because in find parameter does not work with mongodb version < 3

Comment: But when I try to print it or store it into another variable it still shows [object Object] as the output.